# Not able to display my webiew to full height inside dialog in android

Tags: android, xml, webview, fullscreen

I want to display webview inside dialog android but I am not able to see content of it. I have attached the screenshot of it. I have also added the code for it below. Kindly tell me how to resolve it so that it occupies full dialog box.

[image: Screenshot for it]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e4e4e4"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="@string/title_text_Contact_Info" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_close"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/aa" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your `WebView` into container like this

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```